# Created a DOMDocument in php that has children with identical names

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

The XML I am currently trying to build needs to have two `<Location>` elements, one for origin, one for destination, found in the same parent element. I append the first child without a problem, but the elements that would go to the second child end up on the first.

The DOMDocument is being created with a helper function that excepts data for the current node/children.

```
public function set_data(Array $data, $root = null){
    //Check if element exists
    $dom = ($root === null)? $dom = $this->xml : $this->xml->getElementsByTagName($root)->item(0); 

    //Create the element
    $element = ( ! empty( $data['value'] ) ) ? $this->xml->createElement( $data['element'], $data['value'] ): $this->xml->createElement( $data['element']);

    //Add any attributes
    if ( !empty( $data['attributes'] ) && is_array( $data['attributes'] )  ) {
        foreach ( $data['attributes'] as $attribute_key =>  $attribute_value ) {
            $element->setAttribute( $attribute_key, $attribute_value );
        }
    }
    $dom->appendChild($element);

    //add children
    foreach ( $data as $data_key => $child_data ) {
        if(is_array($child_data) && is_numeric($data_key)){
            $this->set_data($child_data, $data['element']);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Input example:

```
array('element' => 'ShipmentLocations', 
    array('element' => 'Location',
        array('element' => 'LocationType', 'value' => 'Origin'),
        array('element' => 'HasLoadingDock', 'value' => 'false')
    ),
    array('element' => 'Location',
        array('element' => 'LocationType', 'value' => 'Destination'),
        array('element' => 'HasLoadingDock', 'value' => 'true')
    )
)...
```

This function uses getElementsByTagName to see if the element exists, if so then add the child to it. I understand something here needs to be changed. Is there currently a way to explicitly state that the child being added should go to the second element, not the first with the identical name? If not, what would be the best work around for this, can namespaces be added with no problem?

Thanks,

Comment: For the time being I have found a work around by passing the "key" of the element. For example, if I want the second location element I will pass a key of 1, and use 1 for `->getElementsByTagName($root)->item(1);`  If no one adds a better answer I will submit my workaround and close this question.

Comment: Do you really need the 'helper' functions? It seems that they make the code a lot more complex. Except for the attributes I would suggest using the DOM methods directly. You can extend the DOM node classes as well.

Comment: Hey ThW, glad to have someone else's opinion. I guess I do not NEED them. My overall goal was to make creation of the xml more simple, not more complex. So whomever creates xml this way would only have to worry about the actual data going into the xml, and not the xml/DOMDocument itself.

Comment: I implemented several approaches into the FluentDOM library. For example [extended methods](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM/blob/master/examples/dom/AppendElement.php) and [nested functions](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM/blob/master/examples/creator/syntax.php).